# Jquery - click handler when using toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue is best described by example:

JS:

```
$(function () {
   $('.classA').on('click', function () { functionA() );
   $('.classB').on('click', function () { functionB() });
} 

var functionA = function()
{
    alert('I am function A');
    $('.classA, .classB').toggleClass('classA classB');
}

var functionB = function ()
{
    alert('I am function B');
    $('.classA, .classB').toggleClass('classA classB');
}
```

The problem is simply put but hard for me to fix: as expected, after pressing class A div, function A is called, class A is toggled to class B, but next time I press the same div, function A is still called, whereas I expect function B to be called then. I am doing something wrong ???

Comment: Just as a tip - This would suffice: `.on('click',functionA);`. The same for the other function.

Comment: You attached the event handler before the element received the new class. You need to look for _delegation_.

Comment: Your functions are missing the keyword `function`. E.g. `function functionA () {...`

Comment: Well, disregard this error, I've edited the question for the right syntax regarding keyword function. In my real code, everything is correct .

Comment: Have you noticed that you are missing the equal sign between var functionB function () ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [delegate the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) from the document to the element with the appropriate class then apply [jQuery's toggleClass function](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to that event.

```
   $(document).on('click','.classA', function () { 
       alert('I am function A');
       $('.classA, .classB').toggleClass('classA classB');
    });

   $(document).on('click','.classB', function () { 
      alert('I am function B');
     $('.classA, .classB').toggleClass('classA classB'); 
    });
```

Comment: This completely solved my question, but! It is partially off-topic, and yet if I write  $(document).on('click','.classA', functionA() ); then functionA is triggered on document load event. This problem goes away if I change it to   ....'.classA', function() {functionA()});

Comment: That was just to give a direction on what you need to do. You can definitely change it based on your need.